iOS in-app purchase transaction doesn't return appAccountToken in Transaction updates
I have added non-renewable subscription in-app purchases in my iOS app using the StoreKit 2 framework. I use the App Store only to confirm the processing of the purchase. I manage all details about the user and subscription (orderId, userIdpurchase date, expiry, etc) on my server. The purchased subscription transactionId gets mapped to an app user and orderId in my database. Every time a user opens the app, I check in my database whether the user has a valid subscription or not.
Since I am giving a subscription to a user of my app (and not mapping to the iOS Apple ID), orderId of my database needs to be mapped to the app store transactionId. So I initiate the product purchase with purchase options in which I pass my orderId as appAccountToken like this:
  let accountTokenUUID = createUUID(from: orderId)
  let purchaseOption = Product.PurchaseOption.appAccountToken(accountTokenUUID)

   do {
        let result = try await product.purchase(options: [purchaseOption])
.
.
.
}

When the purchase is complete, I can extract the orderId from appAccountToken of the Transaction result like this
if let uuid = transaction.appAccountToken {
             retrievedOrderId = extractOrderId(from: uuid)
            print("Extracted order ID: \(retrievedOrderId)")
        } else {
            print("No valid UUID string found in transaction's appAccountToken.")
        }

The problem I am facing is when I am trying to handle pending or interrupted transactions. I have a listener function that receives updates for pending or interrupted transactions. In there the Transaction object shows an empty value for the appAccountToken.
Is there a way I can retrieve back appAccountToken that I had added to the purchase while initiating it for pending or interrupted transactions? If not what else can be done to map my orderId with the app store transactionId for the pending or interrupted transactions?

First of all you need to integrate also the real-time App Store Server Notifications system in your backend.
Basically, you need to provide an endpoint for receiving POST messages from Apple server.
Save the payload from those request and analyze it to understand what is happening.
Read more here:

notificationType

subtype


Workflow:

When you first receive a new purchase you have to save also the originalTransactionId that you will find in the receipt.

Use the originalTransactionId with the Get Transaction Info  API and decode the content as usual.

You will find the appAccountToken in there.


